# Adding a function to title close in jQuery dialog - event not firing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I'm assigning and extra class to Jquery modal .dialog() so I can custom treat the title bar close (.ui-dialog-titlebar-close)

though it doesn't work for some reason

```
    $(".extra_close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function () {
        alert("hello");
    });
```

no alert = just closes the dialog.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you Community

Answer (score 0):

ok after looking more into it (and reading some posts here)

where extra_close is the name of the dialog you are firing up.

```
    $('div.extra_close').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
         alert('hello');
     });
```